# Variable interpolation in regular expressions substitutions

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on Perl programs to parse XML and do regex string replacements on the data. I read a couple of articles on string substitution using Perl.

While replacing the source value with the target string they are using some `$` variables(`$1` ,`$2`, `$3` and `$4` etc.). How does the pattern store the values while doing the string comparison?

Please find some sample code which am looking for.

#### Sample XML file

```xml
  <Para>
    <Hyperlink Display="hide" Protocol="http" URN="https://www.basicurl.org/oid/10.1161/RIA.0000abc">
      AHA
    </Hyperlink>
    (Free)
  </Para>
  <Para>
    <Hyperlink Display="hide" Protocol="http" URN="https://www.abcd.com">
      Background: some text with multiple lines
    </Hyperlink>
    (i have three lines of code)
  </Para>
</Comment>
```

#### Target achievement

```perl
$Str =~ s|<Hyperlink\b[^\>]*?>([^\xFF]*?)([12][890][0-9]{2})([^\xFF]*?)</Hyperlink>|<Emph Emph.Type="Italic">$1</Emph>$2$3|g;
```

To my understanding, we are selecting hyperlink data and replacing the value in `$str`. The `/g` represents a global substitution. What are the values of `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` from the above input file?

Comment: If you need to parse XML, use an XML parsing library like [XML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Parser) or one of the many alternatives. [Classic answer about why you don't want to use res](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: The code is already implemented and i am trying to remove the legacy system and re implemented in the new technology . so i need some help on understanding this regular expression for the above input.

Comment: See [perldoc perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching) for more information about capture groups and the capture variables `$1`, `$2`, ...

Answer (score 2):

When you use a regex pattern there is something called *capturing groups*, which are delimited by parentheses `(...)` in the pattern. They are numbered in the order that their opening parentheses appear in the pattern, and are used to save parts of a string to the built-in Perl variables `$1`, `$2` etc.

For example `/(Hello?)(goo?d)/` captures `hello` or `hell` in `$1`, and `good` or `god` in `$2`

---

#### About your example

```
$Str =~ s|<Hyperlink\b[^\>]*?>([^\xFF]*?)([12][890][0-9]{2})([^\xFF]*?)</Hyperlink>|<Emph Emph.Type="Italic">$1</Emph>$2$3|g;
```

- `([^\xFF]*?)` will capture any character not equal to FF (hexadecimal) from 0 to infinite amount of times. It can capture 0 characters or more not equal to `"\xFF"`
- `([12][890][0-9]{2})` will capture a digit `1` or `2`, followed by a digit `8` `9` or `0`, followed by two digits from `0` to `9`.
- `([^\xFF]*?)` is the same as the first capturing group

Comment: Just a suggestion: Maybe also mention that a capture group is created by enclosing a regex or part of regex in parenthesis?

Comment: Yes , you are right . I just explained it with this example

Comment: Yes that was a good example. My only suggestion is to be even more explicit about it.. A newcomer might not understand everything as easily as we.

Comment: Thanks, but you deleted the explanation about the lazy quantifier. There is a different result if you use *? Or just *

Comment: @Borodin It looks great!